# How to fix Dangerous send security warning in rails generated by brakeman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used **brakeman** for security scan in my application which is in Rails 4.2.
It gave report with Confidence as **High** with Warning Type as **Dangerous send**.
Below is the controller method where I am facing the issue:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @account_name = Rails.application.config.custom.accounts.send(params[:account_name]).name
    @account_logo = Rails.application.config.custom.accounts.send(params[:account_name]).signup_logo
  rescue
    nil
  end
end
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

call methods directly by the user input i.e by params attribute is dangerous security threat, by solving this we must white-list params before calling it inside send.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    method = params[:account_name] || :default_method
    if ["method1", "method2", "method3"].include?(method)
      @account_name = Rails.application.config.custom.accounts.send(method).name
      @account_logo = Rails.application.config.custom.accounts.send(method).signup_logo
    end
  rescue
    nil
  end
end
```